# Does lifting commute with the right action of the fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a map of nice pointed spaces and $\widetilde{f} \colon \widetilde{X} \to \widetilde{Y}$ the lift to the universal covers making
$$
\widetilde{X} \xrightarrow{\widetilde{f}} \widetilde{Y} \\
\downarrow \qquad \downarrow \\
X \,\xrightarrow{f} \,Y
$$
commute and mapping the base points to each other. Let $x \in \widetilde{X}$ and $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to X$ be a loop in $X$. Do we have

$$
\widetilde{f}(x) \,\cdot\, [f \circ \gamma] = \widetilde{f}(x \cdot [\gamma]),
$$
where the dot denotes the right action of the fundamental group on the universal covering?

Comment: $\gamma$ should be a loop and $\tilde{f}(x)$ should belong to the fiber of the basepoint of the loop $\gamma$, isn't it ?

Comment: I agree about the first point, but the fundamental group acts on the whole of the universal covering, if we fix a base point we get a unique isomorphism between the fundamental group and the group of deck transformations.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You're assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected, I think.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Good point. I was a bit vague with saying "nice" spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to prove that the lift $\tilde{\delta}$ of $\delta := f\circ\gamma$ which begins at $\tilde{f}(x)$ is equal to $\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{\gamma}$, where $\tilde{\gamma} : [0;1]\to \tilde{X}$ is the lift of the loop $\gamma$ which begins at $x$. Once we will have proved this, we'll obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde f(x).[f\circ\gamma] &=& \text{endpoint of the lift }\tilde\delta\text{ of }f\circ \gamma\text{ which begins at }\tilde f(x)\\
&= &\text{endpoint of }\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{\gamma}\\
&=& \tilde f(\text{endpoint of }\tilde\gamma)\\
&=& \tilde f(\text{endpoint of the lift of }\gamma\text{ which begins at }x)\\
&=& \tilde f(x.[\gamma]).
\end{eqnarray}

But $$\pi_Y\circ (\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{\gamma}) = f\circ \pi_X\circ \tilde{\gamma} = f\circ \gamma$$
hence $\tilde{f}\circ \tilde\gamma$ is also a lift of $f\circ \gamma$ beginning at $f(x)$, thus $\tilde{f}\circ \tilde\gamma = \tilde{\delta}$ because the lift of $f\circ \gamma$ beginning at $f(x)$ is unique.